# Send a message to every server's system channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying the bot to send a message to every server's system channel, but it always ends up sending it to the top channel on a server. Here's my code so far:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def broadcast(self, ctx, *, text):
        for server in self.client.guilds:
            for system_channel in server.text_channels:
                try:
                    await system_channel.send(text)
                except Exception:
                    continue
                else: break
```

Edit:
Thank you to [TheUntraceable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15295612/theuntraceable)! Here is a working version of it:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def broadcast(self, ctx, *, text):
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            try:
                await guild.system_channel.send(text)
            except Exception:
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**System Channel**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel) attribute that a `discord.Guild` has

Comment: I don't know how to implement it then because either putting it after `server` or after `text_channels` isn't working (line 4).

Comment: You put it after any Guild instance (in your case server) as it's an attribute of discord.Guild. If you get any errors feel free to let me know.

Comment: When using `for system_channel in server.system_channel:` in line 4 and running the command, nothing happens.

Comment: You can just do something like 

`for guild in client.guilds:`
    `await guild.system_channel.send(text)`
P.S Sorry for all these edits im really new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterate the first channel, send the message and `break` at the end stops the loop, thats because the message only sends in the first channel

```
    @commands.command()
    async def broadcast(self, ctx, *, text):
        for server in self.client.guilds:
            for system_channel in server.text_channels:
                try:
                    await system_channel.send(text)
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: It is supposed to send only one message on the servers, but how do I make it sending it in the system channel and not in the channel that is the first one on the server? That is my main problem.